# Which is correct: "gallery for which" or "gallery for whose" or both?

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns, possessives

According to my book this sentence is correct:

> The gallery **for which** I am preparing the exhibition will have to apply for a subsidy from the City council.

I am wondering whether this sentence that I have made is also correct:

> The gallery **for whose** I am preparing the exhibition will have to apply for a subsidy from the City council.

This is the first time I have come across that form in a sentence. I'd appreciate it if you could help me with it, because I think that the first sentence seems not to be correct, as "for which" is not possessive form(?).

Comment: The first version is fine, and your alternative is ungrammatical. The "possessive" aspect (or just any "close relationship", really) is embodied in the preposition ***for*** *(on behalf of which)*. Note that "the gallery" could be expanded upon with other prepositions indicating relationships: *The gallery **to which** I donate money will have to apply for a subsidy*, for example.

Comment: *Whose* is completely wrong here - imagine *the gallery for **his** I am preparing the exhibition…* An easy way to distinguish this is that *who -> he, whom -> him, whose -> his* also don't confuse *whose* with *who's -> he's*

Comment: There is, however, an interesting question being hinted at - whether non-human entities can be referred to as human using *who* - but perhaps this is for a different day…

Comment: The first sentence is absolutely correct. The _cases_ of pronouns in English are provided in every grammar book, as at **[this link.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/cases.htm)** _Which_ is an _interrogative_ pronoun and is used correctly in your first sentence. _Whose_ is the _possessive case_ of _who,_ and its use in the second sentence is nonsensical, since there is nothing for _who_ to _possess!_

Comment: "Which" is a relative pronoun here (**not** an interrogative one) and is fine as complement of the preposition "for". Your second example is ungrammatical, since the relative determiner "whose" requires a following noun (cf. "The gallery for **whose exhibition** a subsidy was required").

Answer (score 1):

> The gallery for which I am preparing the exhibition will have to apply
>   for a subsidy from the City council.

This sentence is correct. "For which" is used with objects like the gallery.

"For whose" would be used with people, e.g.:

> This is the singer for whose appearance (the singer's appearance/his appearance) they were waiting. / This is the guy whose car (the guy's car/his car) was stolen yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

**for which** is a **relative pronoun** that replaces objects, things, abstract nouns,...
**for whose** is a **relative pronoun** that replaces people, or possessive pronouns that refers to people or animals. 
**Gallery** is unanimated, so **whose** is entirely incorrect.
However, **whose** sometimes can refer to inanimate antecedents. For example, **The car whose color is red**. It's unnatural to say **The car which its color is red** 
Here, it **unnatural** to say **The gallery for whose i am preparing the exhibition**, but you can say: **the gallery whose beginning will be next week.**

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23541/can-whose-refer-to-an-inanimate-object

Comment: Thanks @V.V. ! It's new information for me. At least, in this sentence, we can't use whose instead of which.

Comment: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/whose-for-inanimate-objects